# Multi-threading retrieve an existing element from std::map and insert a new element to std::map

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, stdmap

The following sample code wants to thread-safe achieve two things:

1. retrieve an existing element from a `std::map` object, or
2. insert a new element to the same `std::map` object.

Ignore the class `Strategy` because it's only for a kind of computation against `x` and `y`.

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
#include <map>

class MultiThreadingCaching
{
public:
  using KeyType = std::pair< int, int >;

  using Lock = boost::shared_mutex;
  using ReadLock = boost::shared_lock< Lock >;
  using WriteLock = boost::unique_lock< Lock >;

  MultiThreadingCaching( const std::shared_ptr< Strategy > &strategy ) : strategy_( strategy )
  {}

  float access( int x, int y ) const
  {
    const auto key = std::make_pair( x, y );

    // Retrieve
    {
      ReadLock lock( mutex_ );
      if( map_.find( key ) != map_.end() ) {
        return map_[ key ];
      }
    }

    // Insert
    const auto value = strategy_->compute( x, y );
    WriteLock lock( mutex_ );
    map_.insert( { key, value } );

    return value;
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr< Strategy > strategy_;
  mutable std::map< KeyType, float > map_;
  mutable boost::mutex mutex_;
};
```

According to my test, this way is not only NOT faster, but much slower than expected, even slower than `boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex >` for both `ReadLock` and `WriteLock`.

I checked an example [std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) (although I cannot use `std::shared_mutex` for now because I am using C++14). The most significant difference is reader and writer are two separated methods in that example, but my reader and writer are in the same method.

Comment: `if( map_.find( key ) != map_.end() ) { return map_[ key ]; }` makes _two_ lookups in the the map. Do this instead: `auto it = map.find( key ); if( it != map.end() ) return it->second;` and it will only need to do _one_.

Answer (score 0):

you must think why have to program that structure
multithread best structure is best no lock case by thread

your sturucture is read & write that global value map by thread

you need not lock these case

1. map data is read
   because same data

but you need lock from insert action

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).